# NPM React-Canvas package on Meteor client side

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, npm, client-side

I want to use [React-Canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-canvas) on Meteor, so I added:

`meteor add meteorhacks:npm`

And create a **packages.json** file to the root:

```
{
  "react-canvas": "0.0.1"
}
```

But, when I try to use it I have a "window is not defined ..." error.

I search about that, and it's because Meteor can't load Npm packages on client, only on server side.
So, I tried to clone the React-Canvas ./lib directory and put all files into my client/ directory but it's didn't work.

I finaly try to follow [this tutorial](https://react-in-meteor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client-npm/) about browserify npm packages on client.

**app.browserify.options.json**

```
{
  "transforms": {
    "externalify": {
      "global": true,
      "external": {
        "react": "React.require",
        "react-canvas": "React.require"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**app.browserify.js**

```
var ReactCanvas = require('react-canvas');
```

But I got an error:

```
? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'react-canvas'
? (STDERR)     at s (../../../cosmos_browserify/.0.9.2.dgfgwe++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.CosmosBrowserify.os/npm/CosmosBrowserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
? (STDERR)     at s (../../../cosmos_browserify/.0.9.2.dgfgwe++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.CosmosBrowserify.os/npm/CosmosBrowserify/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js:1:1)
```

How can I build a valid .js file to include on my Meteor project to allow me to use React Canvas ?

Comment: npm stands for "node package manager', so it is for packages for node.js, *not* the browser. I don't know how any npm package should be for the client, unless it somehow assumes a webapp framework (such as express) via which it can server to the client. But even then you would need to add some server code. I think you misunderstood the package you are referring to. Could it be for server-side rendering?

Comment: No it's a client side package, it's only used for render canvas elements. 
But it's build for nodejs, so he use some require() function.. I just want to export and be used on personal React component.